# O Mapa (google maps API - javascript) para de funcionar quando eu adiciono uma função no script!

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, funções, google-maps

O mapa para de aparecer quando eu coloco a função LigaTudo, quando eu a removo o mapa volta a aparecer como sempre

```
  var map;
  var markers = [];
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: 75.15975385, lng: -75.15975385},
      zoom: 8
    });
    LigaTudo();
  }
     var i array_nome, array_lat, array_lng ,string_arraynm, string_arraylt, string_arraylg;
string_arraynm= “<?php echo $string_arraynm; ?>“;
 string_arraylt= “<?php echo $string_arraylt; ?>“;
   string_arraylg= “<?php echo $string_arraylg ?>“;
     array_nome = string_arraynm.split(“|”);
       array_lat = string_arraylt.split(“|”);
         array_lng = string_arraylg.split(“|”);
         function LigaTudo(){
          for (var i = array_nome.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var local = new google.maps.LatLng(array_lat[i],array_lng[i]);

            var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
position: local,
title: $array_nome[i]
});

          }
         }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="pontinhos.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=minhachave&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

A parte acima é onde está as funções, abaixo deixo o php(não sei se pode ser algo nele).

```
<?php
$pontonm = array();
$pontolt = array();
$pontolg = array();
// Aqui você se conecta ao banco
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'tcc');
// Executa uma consulta que pega cinco notícias
$sql = "SELECT `nome_pub`,`lat_pub`,`lng_pub` FROM `publicos`";
$query = $mysqli->query($sql);
while ($dados = $query->fetch_assoc()) {


 array_push($pontonm,$dados['nome_pub']);
 array_push($pontolt,$dados['lat_pub']);
 array_push($pontolg,$dados['lng_pub']);
   }




$string_arraynm = implode ( "|",$pontonm);
$string_arraylt = implode ( "|",$pontolt);
$string_arraylg = implode ( "|",$pontolg);
 ?>
```

Gostaria de saber se alguem poderia identificar o problema, e como faço para a usar a função(ela pucha os dados do banco para criar markers) sem que o mapa pare de funcionar, desde já Obrigado.

Comment: checou se dá erro no script? porque tua função `LigaTudo()` tem um `for` controlado pelo tamanho de `array_nome` e dentro percorre as variáveis `array_lat[i] e array_lng[i]`; caso o tamanho de `array_nome` seja maior que o de alguma dessas outras duas, dá pau..